# Render html file outside of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am trying to render a html file that is not in the rails project but use the rails for the route.

I have been trying to set up a path like this, but it will try to link to a file within the public folder.

```
get '/pathtofile', :to => redirect("/path/to/the/other/file.html")
```

I have also tried rendering another file in the controller like this, but with no luck.

```
render "/path/to/the/other/file.html"
```

Is there any way i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the path that Rails uses to look for view templates several ways, including:

```
# example one
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  prepend_view_path 'app/views/mycustomfolder'

# example two
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def self.controller_path
    "mycustomfolder"
  end
```

You could theoretically use this to get out of the app entirely, which is what you're asking to do:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  prepend_view_path 'app/../..' # you are now in the parent folder of the app itself
```

But I think this is going to prove to be a fragile solution. For example, when you host your app, the linked-to file won't go with it, and your link will break. The app is defined by its root folder, and it's best for everything you link to in the app to either be in your app's folder tree or be accessible via a URI.